# Flex + character getting replaced by blank when passed as application param

Tags: apache-flex, character-encoding, flashvars

I am passing a string param into flex application as FlashVars

The param sometime contains special characters, everything shows fine except + sign which gets replaced by blank when it reaches flex.

Here is the scenario for eg.

I have a local variable in JS that gets some values and for this example it can be taken as following

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">   

    var testVar = "some_test_string_that_contains_+_character";

</script>
```

Then to my Flex object AC_FL_RunContent I pass `"FlashVars","test="+testVar`

In the flex code on Init of application I have written

```
var testValue:String = application.parameters["testVar"].toString();
Alert.show(testValue);
```

Now this shows fine except the + character gets replaced by blank. It doesnt happens with other characters like /,@$-_ but the + character.

Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Adobe's docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=passingarguments_3.html):

> **About flashVars properties encoding**
>
> The values of the flashVars properties
>   must be URL encoded. The format of the
>   string is a set of name-value pairs
>   separated by an ampersand (&). You can
>   escape special and nonprintable
>   characters with a percent symbol (%)
>   followed by a two-digit hexadecimal
>   value. You can represent a single
>   blank space using the plus sign (+).

Looking further down at one of the comments from matthew horn, it looks like you can use `%2B` to pass the `+` character.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was reading the variable from the query string which was encoded and then before passing it to flex, I was using testVar = unescape ( testVar ); to pass the actual string. I did not knew that Flashvars have to be passed as encoded. Thanks for the info. This was helpful.

Comment: One thing that was strange is / was going through fine without the need for the url encoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I was having issues with this exact thing.